# Which sentence is correct about ability

Tags: readability

My brother **could** write when he was four, so he **was able to** finish school earlier.

or

My brother **was able** to write when he was four, so he **can** finish school earlier.

Comment: Has he finished school yet or not?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know. I started an English class yesterday and had the participants to do a test to evaluate their knowledge of the english language. There was a third sentence, but it was clearly wrong. I felt that both sentences are correct in a given time frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point:  In your first sentence, *could* is the past tense of *can*, meaning "be able to.  Thus *could* is equivalent to *was able to*, making the introductory clauses equivalent.

Second point: context is everything, so depending on the situation, either of the sentences could be correct.

In the first sentence, all the verbs are in the past tense, so you're talking about time gone by:

> My brother entered the workforce at an early age.  Of course, since he
>   **could write** when he was four, he **was able** to finish school earlier than his peers.

Your brother is out of school and working.  He ability to read and his attendance at school are past events.  Now suppose that you are enrolling your six-year-old brother in school, and you have the following conversation with the principal:

> Principal:  Our curriculum takes six years for pupils to master.
>   You: My brother **could write** when he was four.  I'm sure he **can**
>   finish school earlier.

Now, only your brother's mastery of writing is in the past.  He hasn't yet started school, so his finishing is in the future.  *Can* is an enduring present: you mean that his ability is current and will persist as he progresses quickly through the grades.  You could also say "I'm sure he will be able to finish school earlier."

Only when we know the context can we tell which sentence applies.

Notice that in both cases, *could* is a possible substitute in the second clause:

> My brother could write when he was four, so he **could** finish school earlier.

Your brother has finished school, so *could* is just the past tense of *can*, meaning the same thing as *was able*.  When you're talking to the principal, and you say

> I'm sure he **could** finish school earlier

*could* doesn't refer to past time -- your brother hasn't even started school yet -- but rather it's the modal use of the verb *can*, indicating future possibility.

Comment: Actually, the test, I found these two sentences in, does not tell us the context. It was an online test to assess the students of an English class in Italy. And yes, your answer helped me a lot. Thank you so much.